# JSTL not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, jstl

I have created a sample page with a single **JSTL line and it is not displaying anything**. I am running it on a JBoss 7.1 server. I manage all the project using Eclipse.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```

PageController.java

```
@Controller
public class PageController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

WebMvcConfig.java

```
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    //Set default servlet handler, this is the same as <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    /*@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }*/
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html><body>
<c:out value="${header['user-agent']}" default="unknown"/>
</body></html>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>My Project</name>
    <properties>
        <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
        <springVersion>3.2.6.RELEASE</springVersion>
        <hibernateVersion>4.2.8.Final</hibernateVersion>
        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>springsource-repo</id>
            <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dynamic Web Module 3.0 with JSTL -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>3.1</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>2.4</version> -->
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.6.v20130930</version>
                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <host>localhost</host>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.16</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!--<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: Why JSTL is not working ?

Comment: What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: Please don't say "it's not displaying anything".  Could be lots of reasons, all unknown because it has nothing to do with the code you posted.  If your WAR didn't deploy, you'll get an HTTP 404 response instead of 200.  Check the logs and see if it deployed correctly.  Take out the JSTL and hard code "hello world" in the HTML.  If that doesn't work, you know it's not JSTL.

Comment: I get a blank page with no error, I can see harcoded text/html but JSTL is not working with those lines:
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:out value="${header['user-agent']}" default="unknown"/>

Comment: Do you see `unknown` or nothing at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using Servlet 2.5 instead of Servlet 3.x